# Fatal error on OnepageController.php

Tags: orders, magento-1, onepage-checkout, fatal-error, onestepcheckout

I am trying to update order summary block on payment method change but it display

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in **C:\xampp\htdocs\young\app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php** on line **172**

```
170 protected function _getReviewHtml()
171 {
172    return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->toHtml();
173 }


public function orderupdateAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
    $result['update_section'] = array(
        'name' => 'review',
        'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
    );
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will be an issue with the `layout.xml` and your custom controller action.

Magento cannot find the `root` block for your action and fatals when trying to call `toHtml` on it.

Adding the following to create an empty root block into your `checkout.xml` layout should allow you to not fatal.

```
<checkout_onepage_orderupdate>
    <block name="root" type="core/template"/>
</checkout_onepage_orderupdate>
```

(Obviously if you want `_getReviewHtml` to return something viable you will have to pop a valid block in the layout definition, as currently it will just return nothing)